# to return an html result in loop in a function to a different page

Tags: php

I have a class

```
class files{

  function displayhtml(){?> 

select name="df">

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){?>

         <option value="<?php echo "$i"; ?>"><?php echo "$i"; ?></option><?php
        }?></select><?php
  }
}
?>
```

I have a file newgetfile.php, i need to display this drop down in newgetfile.php by calling this function in newgetfile.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the html part as string.

```
function displayhtml(){ 

$string  = '<select name="df">';

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){?>

         $string .= '<option value="' . $i .'">' . $i . '</option>';

  }

$string .= '</select>';
return $string;
}
```

Comment: how $string="html contents",       could you give a small eg

Comment: i shoulld be able to return the whole drop down results from <select> to </select>

Comment: It should be like $string = "select name="df">";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){?>

       $string .=  "<option value="<?php echo "$i"; ?>"><?php echo "$i"; ?></option>
        }?></select>"
  }
return $string;

Comment: use all the html tags data as a string, use string concatenation and return it finally.

Comment: I will be back about the result here shortly

Comment: BUT IS that possible to pass as string we r using html and php together

Comment: drop down is dispalyed with some unwanted characters

Comment: put </select> out side the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
class files
{

    public static function displayhtml() { 

        $string  = '<select name="df">';

        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $string .= '<option value="' . $i .'">' . $i . '</option>';
        }

        $strin .= '</select>';

        return $string;
    }
}


echo files::displayhtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take all drop down code in one php variable and can return it to where you want to display it..